# Typing svelte $store variable

Tags: typescript, types, svelte, svelte-store

I wanted to know if it is possible de type the dollar sign value of a custom svelte store ?

From [this example](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) :

**app.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import { count } from './stores.js';
</script>

<h1>The count is {$count}</h1>

<button on:click={count.increment}>+</button>
<button on:click={count.decrement}>-</button>
<button on:click={count.reset}>reset</button>
```

**stores.js**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

function createCount() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(0);

    return {
        subscribe,
        increment: () => {},
        decrement: () => {},
        reset: () => {}
    };
}

export const count = createCount();
```

How do you type the variable `{$count}` with your own typescript interface ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can rename your `stores.js` to `stores.ts` and add a type, like:

```
import { Writable, writable } from "svelte/store"

type CountStore = {
  subscribe: Writable<number>["subscribe"]
    
  increment: () => void
  decrement: () => void
  reset: () => void
}

function createCount(): CountStore {
.
.
.
```

---

### EDIT:

You don't need to define the type, Typescript does it great, so you can just rename the original file from `js` to `ts`.

Comment: Just in case, this does not work in while using Vite for a Svelte project.

Comment: Is ther guidance on how to do this using vite?

Comment: Although it is an old question, I think there is something wrong! Why do you import `writable` twice? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MBParvezRony 10x for the correction.

Comment: This really does not answer the question if you're not using Typescript. :(